# How to tell where a Scala project "starts"?

Tags: scala

I'm moving to Scala from a Python background, and am getting kind of overwhelmed with the fact that everything is an object. I'm having trouble tracing where the execution of the project begins.

What are some methods for finding where a Scala project's controlling logic begins?

Comment: Somewhere there is a `main` method defined in an `object` or somewhere there is an object that `extends App` or maybe something like `IOApp` or `ZioApp` - Anyways, it is usual that such object would be called `Main`

Comment: In Python, everything is an object, too. There is not much difference between Python and Scala in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sbt, you can:

```
show discoveredMainClasses
```

and it will show you all the entry points:

- (Scala 2 and 3) all the `object`s with `main` methods, including those that get a `main` by doing `extends App`
- (Scala 3 only) all the methods annotated `@main`

`run` will bring up a menu asking you to choose an entry point, if more than one is found within a project.

That said, some frameworks use their own entry points that aren't necessarily `main` methods. In those cases, there are only framework-specific answers.